# Jquery .each() infinite loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, iterator, each

I am trying to make an infinite loop using jquery so the bars will never stop animating unless this line is executed:

$(".onoffswitch-active").click(function(){

I tried looping through the "span" tags but it just works for a short while, how can I make it loop infinitely till the user clicks on "onoffswitch-active", thanks.

The jquery code:

```
var t= Math.random() * 500

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".onoffswitch-inactive").click(function(){
   $('span').each(function(x){
    $("#bar1").animate({height:Math.random() * 300},"t");
    $("#bar2").animate({height:Math.random() * 300},"t");
    $("#bar3").animate({height:Math.random() * 300},"t");
    $("#bar4").animate({height:Math.random() * 300},"t");
    $("#bar5").animate({height:Math.random() * 300},"t");
    $("#bar6").animate({height:Math.random() * 300},"t");
    $("#bar7").animate({height:Math.random() * 300},"t");
    $("#bar8").animate({height:Math.random() * 300},"t");
    $("#bar9").animate({height:Math.random() * 300},"t");
    $("#bar10").animate({height:Math.random() * 300},"t");
    $("#bar11").animate({height:Math.random() * 300},"t");
    $("#bar12").animate({height:Math.random() * 300},"t");
    $("#bar13").animate({height:Math.random() * 300},"t");
    $("#bar14").animate({height:Math.random() * 300},"t");
    $("#bar15").animate({height:Math.random() * 300},"t");
    $("#bar16").animate({height:Math.random() * 300},"t");
    $("#bar17").animate({height:Math.random() * 300},"t");
    $("#bar18").animate({height:Math.random() * 300},"t");
    $("#bar19").animate({height:Math.random() * 300},"t");
    $("#bar20").animate({height:Math.random() * 300},"t");
    $("#bar21").animate({height:Math.random() * 300},"t");
    $("#bar22").animate({height:Math.random() * 300},"t");
    $("#bar23").animate({height:Math.random() * 300},"t");
    $("#bar24").animate({height:Math.random() * 300},"t");
    $("#bar25").animate({height:Math.random() * 300},"t");
    $("#bar26").animate({height:Math.random() * 300},"t");
    $("#bar27").animate({height:Math.random() * 300},"t");
    $("#bar28").animate({height:Math.random() * 300},"t");
    $("#bar29").animate({height:Math.random() * 300},"t");
    $("#bar30").animate({height:Math.random() * 300},"t");
    $("#bar31").animate({height:Math.random() * 300},"t");
    $("#bar32").animate({height:Math.random() * 300},"t");
    $("#bar33").animate({height:Math.random() * 300},"t");
    $("#bar34").animate({height:Math.random() * 300},"t");
    $("#bar35").animate({height:Math.random() * 300},"t");
    $("#bar36").animate({height:Math.random() * 300},"t");
    $("#bar37").animate({height:Math.random() * 300},"t");
    $("#bar38").animate({height:Math.random() * 300},"t");
    $("#bar39").animate({height:Math.random() * 300},"t");
    $("#bar40").animate({height:Math.random() * 300},"t");
    $("#bar41").animate({height:Math.random() * 300},"t");
    $("#bar42").animate({height:Math.random() * 300},"t");
    $("#bar43").animate({height:Math.random() * 300},"t");
    $("#bar44").animate({height:Math.random() * 300},"t");
    $("#bar45").animate({height:Math.random() * 300},"t");
    $("#bar46").animate({height:Math.random() * 300},"t");
    $("#bar47").animate({height:Math.random() * 300},"t");
    $("#bar48").animate({height:Math.random() * 300},"t");
    $("#bar49").animate({height:Math.random() * 300},"t");
    $("#bar50").animate({height:Math.random() * 300},"t");
    $("#bar51").animate({height:Math.random() * 300},"t");
    $("#bar52").animate({height:Math.random() * 300},"t");
    $("#bar53").animate({height:Math.random() * 300},"t");
    $("#bar54").animate({height:Math.random() * 300},"t");
    $("#bar55").animate({height:Math.random() * 300},"t");
    $("#bar56").animate({height:Math.random() * 300},"t");
    $("#bar57").animate({height:Math.random() * 300},"t");
    $("#bar58").animate({height:Math.random() * 300},"t");
    $("#bar59").animate({height:Math.random() * 300},"t");
    $("#bar60").animate({height:Math.random() * 300},"t");
   });
  });



  $(".onoffswitch-active").click(function(){
    $(":animated").stop(true,true);
    $("#bar1").animate({height:0},"slow");
    $("#bar2").animate({height:0},"slow");
    $("#bar3").animate({height:0},"slow");
    $("#bar4").animate({height:0},"slow");
    $("#bar5").animate({height:0},"slow");
    $("#bar6").animate({height:0},"slow");
    $("#bar7").animate({height:0},"slow");
    $("#bar8").animate({height:0},"slow");
    $("#bar9").animate({height:0},"slow");
    $("#bar10").animate({height:0},"slow");
    $("#bar11").animate({height:0},"slow");
    $("#bar12").animate({height:0},"slow");
    $("#bar13").animate({height:0},"slow");
    $("#bar14").animate({height:0},"slow");
    $("#bar15").animate({height:0},"slow");
    $("#bar16").animate({height:0},"slow");
    $("#bar17").animate({height:0},"slow");
    $("#bar18").animate({height:0},"slow");
    $("#bar19").animate({height:0},"slow");
    $("#bar20").animate({height:0},"slow");
    $("#bar21").animate({height:0},"slow");
    $("#bar22").animate({height:0},"slow");
    $("#bar23").animate({height:0},"slow");
    $("#bar24").animate({height:0},"slow");
    $("#bar25").animate({height:0},"slow");
    $("#bar26").animate({height:0},"slow");
    $("#bar27").animate({height:0},"slow");
    $("#bar28").animate({height:0},"slow");
    $("#bar29").animate({height:0},"slow");
    $("#bar30").animate({height:0},"slow");
    $("#bar31").animate({height:0},"slow");
    $("#bar32").animate({height:0},"slow");
    $("#bar33").animate({height:0},"slow");
    $("#bar34").animate({height:0},"slow");
    $("#bar35").animate({height:0},"slow");
    $("#bar36").animate({height:0},"slow");
    $("#bar37").animate({height:0},"slow");
    $("#bar38").animate({height:0},"slow");
    $("#bar39").animate({height:0},"slow");
    $("#bar40").animate({height:0},"slow");
    $("#bar41").animate({height:0},"slow");
    $("#bar42").animate({height:0},"slow");
    $("#bar43").animate({height:0},"slow");
    $("#bar44").animate({height:0},"slow");
    $("#bar45").animate({height:0},"slow");
    $("#bar46").animate({height:0},"slow");
    $("#bar47").animate({height:0},"slow");
    $("#bar48").animate({height:0},"slow");
    $("#bar49").animate({height:0},"slow");
    $("#bar50").animate({height:0},"slow");
    $("#bar51").animate({height:0},"slow");
    $("#bar52").animate({height:0},"slow");
    $("#bar53").animate({height:0},"slow");
    $("#bar54").animate({height:0},"slow");
    $("#bar55").animate({height:0},"slow");
    $("#bar56").animate({height:0},"slow");
    $("#bar57").animate({height:0},"slow");
    $("#bar58").animate({height:0},"slow");
    $("#bar59").animate({height:0},"slow");
    $("#bar60").animate({height:0},"slow");


  });
});
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="onoffswitch">
    <div class="onoffswitch">
    <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch">
    <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
    <div class="onoffswitch-inner">
    <div class="onoffswitch-active" onClick="stop();">ON</div>
    <div class="onoffswitch-inactive" onClick="play();">OFF</div>
    </div>

    </label>
    </div> 
</div>


<div class="eq">
    <span id="bar1" class="bar"></span>
    <span id="bar2" class="bar"></span>
    <span id="bar3" class="bar"></span>
    <span id="bar4" class="bar"></span>
    <span id="bar5" class="bar"></span>
    <span id="bar6" class="bar"></span>
    <span id="bar7" class="bar"></span>
    <span id="bar8" class="bar"></span>
    <span id="bar9" class="bar"></span>
    <span id="bar10" class="bar"></span>
    <span id="bar11" class="bar"></span>
    <span id="bar12" class="bar"></span>
    <span id="bar13" class="bar"></span>
    <span id="bar14" class="bar"></span>
    <span id="bar15" class="bar"></span>
    <span id="bar16" class="bar"></span>
    <span id="bar17" class="bar"></span>
    <span id="bar18" class="bar"></span>
    <span id="bar19" class="bar"></span>
    <span id="bar20" class="bar"></span>
    <span id="bar21" class="bar"></span>
    <span id="bar22" class="bar"></span>
    <span id="bar23" class="bar"></span>
    <span id="bar24" class="bar"></span>
    <span id="bar25" class="bar"></span>
    <span id="bar26" class="bar"></span>
    <span id="bar27" class="bar"></span>
    <span id="bar28" class="bar"></span>
    <span id="bar29" class="bar"></span>
    <span id="bar30" class="bar"></span>
    <span id="bar31" class="bar"></span>
    <span id="bar32" class="bar"></span>
    <span id="bar33" class="bar"></span>
    <span id="bar34" class="bar"></span>
    <span id="bar35" class="bar"></span>
    <span id="bar36" class="bar"></span>
    <span id="bar37" class="bar"></span>
    <span id="bar38" class="bar"></span>
    <span id="bar39" class="bar"></span>
    <span id="bar40" class="bar"></span>
    <span id="bar41" class="bar"></span>
    <span id="bar42" class="bar"></span>
    <span id="bar43" class="bar"></span>
    <span id="bar44" class="bar"></span>
    <span id="bar45" class="bar"></span>
    <span id="bar46" class="bar"></span>
    <span id="bar47" class="bar"></span>
    <span id="bar48" class="bar"></span>
    <span id="bar49" class="bar"></span>
    <span id="bar50" class="bar"></span>
    <span id="bar51" class="bar"></span>
    <span id="bar52" class="bar"></span>
    <span id="bar53" class="bar"></span>
    <span id="bar54" class="bar"></span>
    <span id="bar55" class="bar"></span>
    <span id="bar56" class="bar"></span>
    <span id="bar57" class="bar"></span>
    <span id="bar58" class="bar"></span>
    <span id="bar59" class="bar"></span>
    <span id="bar60" class="bar"></span>


</div>
```

The CSS:

```
#bar1,#bar2,#bar3,#bar4,#bar5,#bar6,#bar7,#bar8,#bar9,#bar10,#bar11,#bar12,#bar13,#bar14,#bar15,#bar16,#bar17,#bar18,#bar19,#bar20,#bar21,#bar22,#bar23,#bar24,#bar25,#bar26,#bar27,#bar28,#bar29,#bar30,#bar31,#bar32,#bar33,#bar34,#bar35,#bar36,#bar37,#bar38,#bar39,#bar40,#bar41,#bar42,#bar43,#bar44,#bar45,#bar46,#bar47,#bar48,#bar49,#bar50,#bar51,#bar52,#bar53,#bar54,#bar55,#bar56,#bar57,#bar58,#bar59,#bar60,#bar61,#bar62,#bar63,#bar64,#bar65,#bar66,#bar67,#bar68
{
    background-color: white;
    width:20px;
    height:0px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Comment: Coding 101, When you see the same lines pasted over and over again with a small change, you are doing it wrong.

Comment: Learn how to use "for" loops !

Comment: The code makes no sense, looping through multiple spans but calling same elements with ids? You are basically just stomping on the previous event. If you have multiple elements with the same id, that is also a major bug since ids are singular. Learn how to use a class selector, 60 lines will be *ONE*.

Comment: Woot, did you really repeat that snippet 60 times? Please, use a class selector or at least a loop and keep your code [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DRY)

Comment: You want to hear about [`[name^="value"]`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector.

Comment: @moonwave99: No, actually he wants to remove the ids from his elements and use a class

Comment: `animate({...},"t");` remove the quotes around `t` otherwise the animation will use a default value

Comment: @h2ooooooo, I rolled that edit back since you changed the code way to drastic. Make the suggestion in an answer, not the original post.

Comment: Set an Interval using setInterval , and on click use cleatInterval

Comment: @epascarello, Yoshi - I did it to improve reading as it's not an actual answer. I wouldn't have posted it as an answer, seeing as it doesn't fix the code - the code does exactly the same, and I only did it to improve everyone elses respond time. I'll keep this in mind in the future, though.

Comment: @h2ooooooo, but it drastically changed the answer. Chop out 100 of the animate lines if you want it shorter. lol

Comment: @epascarello It hasn't drastically changed the question, nor the answer, as both will be the same. The OP's question wasn't "how can I get rid of these 60 lines of code" but rather "how can I use an interval to keep these bars animating", and therefore the answer and the question remain the same no matter how you format the 60 lines. Just my 1 cent though, and as said, I'll keep this in mind in the future. I never meant to offend anyone, let alone create a discussion about it, as I simply did it for other people to read it more easily, and didn't feel it deserved an answer (as again, it isn't)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you did not provide your html, I used my own, but maybe the follwing will help you:

```
var
  duration = Math.random() * 500,
  isAnimating = false;

// start animations
function startAnmation() {
  isAnimating = true;
  $('#wrapper .bar').each(function () {
    (function loop($el) {
      $el.animate({
        height: Math.random() * 300
      }, {
        duration: duration,
        complete: function () {
          if (isAnimating) {
            loop($el);
          }
        }
      });
    }($(this)));
  });
}

// stop animations
function stopAnmation() {
  isAnimating = false;
  $('#wrapper .bar').stop(false);
}

// bind click events
$('#onoffswitch').on({
  click: function() {
    if ($(this).toggleClass('inactive active').is('.active')) {
      startAnmation();
    } else {
      stopAnmation();
    }
  }
});
```

works with the following html:

```
<button id="onoffswitch" class="inactive">start/stop</button>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
</div>​
```

and some css:

```
#wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.bar {
  float: left;
  width: 20px;
  background: #efefef;
  margin-right: 1px;
}​
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Y2Sjf/1/

Comment: Edited my question to include my html code. I'm new to this, so any sort of help or improvement would be appreciated :). Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can also accomplish this animation with CSS3:

JS:

```
$("#toggleButton").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("running");

    var doAnim = function(){
        if ($("#toggleButton").hasClass("running")){
            $("#buttonbar .bar").each(function(){
                $(this).css("height", Math.round(Math.random() * 99 + 1) + "%");
            });
            setTimeout(doAnim, 250);
        }
    };
    doAnim();
});​​​​​​
```

CSS

```
#buttonbar .bar{
    width:20px;
    background:#fff;
    margin-right:3px;
    float:left;
    overflow:hidden;

    -webkit-transition:height .25s; /* Note I only included the webkit transition */
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WuFZd/

Comment: I like answers that allow use of graphics accelerators.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery .each function will not work to produce an infinite loop unless you have an infinite number of elements to loop through. You are better served in this case by creating a while loop out of pure javascript.

Comment: Yeah, I think you need to use setInterval/setTimeout, otherwise the browser will be locked up, as mentioned by epascarello's comment in a different answer.

Answer (score 0):

`.each()` is not the correct way to do it. You need to use `setInterval`

For example, you try something like this

```
$(".onoffswitch-inactive").click(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
          $("#bar1").animate({height:Math.random() * 300},"t");
    }, 300); //run every 300 milliseconds. 
}
```

And Clear the interval using `clearInterval`

Comment: No, you should not use `setInterval` for infinite animations

Comment: why I should not use `setInterval`?

Comment: It can drift from the animations (and btw. 10ms is much too less). Just use the animation callback for a much cleaner solution.

Comment: Right, 10ms was too less and it should be more. I just wanted to give him a idea of using `setInterval`.

Comment: While `getAnimationFrame` is probably the most correct way to animate infinitely, I don't think `setInterval` is completely wrong.

Comment: @Shmiddty: That's true for the internals of `.animate`, but we want to implement a endless animation on a higher level

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems odd, but basically give the elements a class and do something like this.

```
var bars = $(".bars");

function loop() {
    var len = bars.length;
    bars.each(function() {
        $(this).animate({height: Math.floor(Math.random() * 300)}, "slow");
    });
    bars.animate({height: 0}, "slow", function() {
                                          if (!--len) loop();
                                      });
}
loop();
```

Answer (score -3):

Disclaimer: quick hack!

Replace this code:

```
$('span').each(function(x){
```

with:

```
runAnimation = true;
while(runAnimation) {
```

and this code:

```
$(":animated").stop(true,true);
```

add:

```
$(":animated").stop(true,true);
runAnimation = false;
```

Comment: that while loop is going to lock up the browser and it will be impossible for animations to run.

Comment: Maybe put a setTimeOut in there somewhere... :D

Comment: `setTimeout` won't help. Once single-threaded code is blocked, it's blocked.

Comment: Agreed. This was a bad answer.